# Estimating effect size for mixed effects model with interaction

Tags: r, mixed-models

I'm trying to get effect sizes for a linear mixed effects model which includes a significant four-way interaction in R and am struggling to understand how to do this because of the interaction. I'd really appreciate some clear advice (and optimally code to do this). Thanks for allhelp!

```
m1 <-lmer(A ~ B*C*D*F+(1|Item)+(1|Subject),data=data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using [version 0.9.0 of the `marginaleffects` package for `R`.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) (Disclaimer: I am the author.) For simplicity, note that the model only includes a 3-way interaction, but the same logic applies.

The first important thing to realize is that there is no unique "effect" for a regressor in such a model. Indeed, our estimate will typically vary from individual to individual, depending on the values of all the predictors in the interaction. For example, using the `comparisons()` function we can estimate what happens to the predicted value of `mpg` when `hp` increases by 1-unit:

```r
library(lme4)
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- lmer(mpg ~ hp * am * vs + (1 | carb), data = mtcars)

comparisons(mod, variables = "hp")
# 
#  Term Contrast Estimate Std. Error       z  Pr(>|z|)    2.5 %   97.5 %
#    hp       +1 -0.03690    0.01250 -2.9508 0.0031700 -0.06141 -0.01239
#    hp       +1 -0.03690    0.01250 -2.9508 0.0031700 -0.06141 -0.01239
#    hp       +1 -0.11979    0.04525 -2.6471 0.0081193 -0.20849 -0.03109
#    hp       +1 -0.06573    0.05510 -1.1930 0.2328736 -0.17372  0.04226
#    hp       +1 -0.01632    0.02855 -0.5716 0.5675634 -0.07227  0.03963
# --- 22 rows omitted. See ?avg_comparisons and ?print.marginaleffects --- 
#    hp       +1 -0.11979    0.04525 -2.6471 0.0081193 -0.20849 -0.03109
#    hp       +1 -0.03690    0.01250 -2.9508 0.0031700 -0.06141 -0.01239
#    hp       +1 -0.03690    0.01250 -2.9508 0.0031700 -0.06141 -0.01239
#    hp       +1 -0.03690    0.01250 -2.9508 0.0031700 -0.06141 -0.01239
#    hp       +1 -0.11979    0.04525 -2.6471 0.0081193 -0.20849 -0.03109 
# 
# Prediction type:  response 
# Columns: rowid, type, term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted, predicted_hi, predicted_lo, mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb, eps
```

Note that the output of `comparisons()` had 32 rows, because the original data had 32 rows. Often times, people find this too unwieldy to interpret. Instead, they compute the average for different values of the predictors. For example:

```r
avg_comparisons(mod, variables = "hp", by = c("am", "vs"))
# 
#  Term Contrast am vs Estimate Std. Error       z  Pr(>|z|)    2.5 %   97.5 %
#    hp mean(+1)  1  0 -0.03690    0.01250 -2.9508 0.0031700 -0.06141 -0.01239
#    hp mean(+1)  1  1 -0.11979    0.04525 -2.6471 0.0081193 -0.20849 -0.03109
#    hp mean(+1)  0  1 -0.06573    0.05510 -1.1930 0.2328736 -0.17372  0.04226
#    hp mean(+1)  0  0 -0.01632    0.02855 -0.5716 0.5675634 -0.07227  0.03963
# 
# Prediction type:  response 
# Columns: type, term, contrast, am, vs, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted, predicted_hi, predicted_lo
```

What this tells us is that for an individual with `am`=1 and `vs`=0, increasing `hp` by 1 unit is associated with a change of -0.0368982 in the predicted value of `mpg` (our dependent variable). For an individual with `am`=1 and `vs`=1, increasing `hp` by 1 unit is associated with a change of -0.1197907 in the predicted value of `mpg`.

I recommend you check out the tutorials on the `marginaleffects` website, and in particular [the article on “Comparisons”.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/comparisons.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful! Since as you point out here, there is no unique effect in interactions, do you have any recommendations on best practice for reporting effect sizes for such models? Would you just define it more narrowly and have to say "for subjects where am = 1, vs = 0, hp = 1, then effect size is Cohen's D = X"?

Comment: But this is fairly meaningless, I guess, since effect sizes will likely vary wildly for different constellations of the interaction...

Comment: What you describe is one good option: choose a few "representative" individuals and interpret there. There are lots of other option. See this vignette, and the post we link to from Harrell: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/logit.html

Comment: Sorry to hijack this, but I asked a related question (link below) and maybe easily answer it with your package. For this question I'm looking at a quality (length) of 3 genes in response to a treatment for an experiment repeated 4 times (formula is: length ~ gene*treatment +(1|replicate). Can I use  avg_comparisons(lmObject, variables = "treatment", by = "gene") to look at the effect of treatment for each gene individually??

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77248092/interpreting-the-output-of-a-glm-with-an-interaction-factor-for-within-group-com